# It can be said that there exists that which can be hyperapproximatively thought or imagined, or even the "post-thought", "post-imagined"?

Tags: metaphysics

Continuation of the question -> meta-thought, meta-imagined and/or even the non-thought, the non-imagined?

As we know, in spirituality, someone says that all and everything is not just possible, but already exist.

Ok...but now the problem is if there is some way to access it?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy SE :) I had a hard time understanding your question because I don't know what you mean by all the terms, and I suspect all but a few specialists amongst us here would know them. I googled "hyperapproximatvely" and got a bunch of links for ADHD treatment :-P

Comment: Reminds me of Ervin Lazlo and his Akashic Fields stuff.  Interesting but not my cup of tea.

Comment: No no, iperapprossimativamente è un termine che ho coniato io al momento...è per far capire qualcosadi veramente lontano da immaginare...è una specie di superiperbole.

Comment: @Raffaele In particular, when coining new concepts it is necessary to introduce them by a definition which links them to known concepts. I do not know what a thing "veramente lontano da immaginare" could be. Please give an example.

Comment: Jo Wehler ad esempio infinite entità infinitamente maggiori di infiniti onniversi onniplicati all'onni-infinito...

Comment: Perhaps contact a Philosopher with your native language and get a start there?